Systemd unit that start when network interface is turn off
I'm writing a python script that will execute a function when the VPN is disconnected. And can I create a systemd unit that will notify me if interface tun0 (vpn) is down, instead of doing ifconfig tun0 every second? I mean suddenly turn off, because I see many examples of notifications when interface is on.
I want a solution without no need query ifconfig every second
UPD: I try write unit, like
    [Unit]
    Description=Listen when interface is down
    After=network.target
    After=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    Restart=on-failure
    ExecStart=/path/to/run.sh

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

But this script start only when network interface is UP. And I need solution when this interface is DOWN. Not check, if tun0 is DOWN at the moment, but wait for event if it's DOWN and do the work

What have you tried in order to achieve this? This isn't a service where people will do the work for you. People are willing to help but you are more likely to receive help if you give an effort and show where it isn't working than you are if you ask people to do it for you.

It's a forum where people asking for help, right? If i know where it isn't working, I will find answer. I can't found any information about something like Wanted=network-offline.target or any event when kernel says about interface  is down. I mean event ifdown, not status or funcion

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm suggesting that you make an attempt and then show in the question where the attempt isn't working. There is nothing requiring you to do this and while people come here to ask for for help, you are more likely to receive help if you make an effect rather than just asking others to do it for you when you haven't even attempted anything on your own.

I even don't know is that possible. I wrote a unit that does a similar thing, but I don't know if it's possible to break down what I need. So I can't give an example of a broken script. I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

It is possible for you to write a service file, test it, and add it to the question including where it doesn't work. That is what people usually do. What is stopping you from trying and making an effort? If you can register at a forum and post a question, then there is nothing stopping you from doing that.

Do you have problems with formal logic? How can you write an example of something that probably doesn't exist?Thanks anyway.  I made sure, once again, that such forums are not a place to find answers to difficult questions

Note a possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643290/can-systemd-networkd-notify-when-network-goes-down -- no answer, but a possibly useful comment.

Systemd only keeps track of device appearance or disappearance, but not of network interface up/down events. The After= will be satisfied when the interface exists, not when it goes up nor when it gets configured.
If you want a service to be started in reaction to a .device unit appearing, you can link it from that unit's Wants= (e.g. by symlinking under sys-devices-[...].device.wants/, or by using udev to set SYSTEMD_WANTS+="foo.service"). There is no equivalent way to start anything in reaction to .device unit disappearing, although that could be achieved using raw udev rules – for example, a rule could match on ACTION=="remove", [...] and invoke RUN+="/bin/something".
Up/down state is not tracked by .device units and is something that systemd-networkd would handle instead (which can be scripted using networkd-broker or networkd-dispatcher).
Programs can receive interface up/down notifications via Netlink (specifically rtnetlink). You can see rtnl events in ip monitor and access this from Python using the pyroute2 module.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import pyroute2
import syslog

ipr = pyroute2.IPRoute()
ipr.bind()
while True:
    for msg in ipr.get():
        if msg["event"] == "RTM_NEWLINK":
            # NEWLINK can mean either a new interface or a change to the status
            # of an existing interface.
            state = msg["state"]
            ifname = next(v for (k, v) in msg["attrs"] if k == "IFLA_IFNAME")
            if ifname == "tun0" and state == "down":
                syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_NOTICE, "tun0 went down")
        elif msg["event"] == "RTM_DELLINK":
            ifname = next(v for (k, v) in msg["attrs"] if k == "IFLA_IFNAME")
            if ifname == "tun0":
                syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_NOTICE, "tun0 disappeared")

The ifplugd service can also be used to run scripts on interface state change, but it is old and does not use Netlink; instead it polls interface state via legacy ioctl() every second. It is, however, written by the same Lennart Poettering as systemd, so it might be the closest thing to a "systemd built-in" feature (for interfaces which aren't handled by systemd-networkd).

Thank you. I expected it to be impossible, but I didn't know what course of action to choose next. You have helped me a lot.
